# MySQL Query showing only the last item grouped by user

Tags: php, mysql

I got a database that registers user actions and their geolocation.
Now I would like to fetch this data at the hand of the last action per user.

The table looks a bit like:

- geoaction_id AUTO INCREMENT
- geoaction_user
- geoaction_creationdate (Y-m-d H:i:s)
- geoaction_action
- geoaction_lon
- geoaction_lat

Now I would like to make a simple query that selects of all users the last item.

But LIMIT 0,1 just parses one row no matter what. (LOGICALLY!!)

Group by gives a little better result.

But how to get only the last item per user?

Comment: Try using MAX function along with group by maybe ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column.html. Can you post some sample data and also what should the output look like ?

Comment: What is the query that you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please provide the queries you have checked out so far, in order to assist you better.

```
    SELECT geoaction_user, geoaction_action 
    FROM table-name
    GROUP BY geoaction_user 
    ORDER BY geoaction_action DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with sets:

```
SELECT
    g.geoaction_user,
    g.geoaction_action,
    g.geoaction_creationdate,
    g.geoaction_lat,
    g.geoaction_lon
FROM
    (
     SELECT
         geoaction_user,
         MAX(geoaction_id) max_id
     FROM
         geoactions
     GROUP BY geoaction_user
     ) s
JOIN
    geoactions g
    ON s.geoaction_user = g.geoaction_user
         AND s.max_id = geoaction_id
```

The subquery generates a virtual table with the geoaction_id from the latest entry in the tabble for each user_id, then the table is joined to get the data belong to the latest id.

If you need to filter out some records place the where clause in the subquery